# Determining the constructor of a data type instance

Tags: haskell, constructor, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

have I coded myself into a corner?  I have a data type that's near the entry point of my program

```
data Token = A String | B String deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

In a library module, I have

```
type Constructor token = String -> token
```

Back towards the entry point, I have something like

```
constructor :: Constructor Token
constructor = A
tokenA :: Token
tokenA = A "a"
tokenB :: Token
tokenB = B "b"
```

Somewhere in the middle, between entry point and library, what I want to use is

```
tokenUsesConstructor :: Constructor token -> token -> Bool
```

so that some things can be done to the `A`s and different things can be done to the `B`s.  The following doesn't work ofc because parameters cannot be repeated:

```
tokenUsesConstructor constructor (constructor _) = True
tokenUsesConstructor constructor (_ _)           = False
-- use.hs:21:35: error: Parse error in pattern: constructor
```

and, as the error shows (indicating the first of the two lines above), the problem is more fundamental than that, as is also shown by

```
tokenUsesConstructor constructor token =
    case token of
        constructor _ -> True
         _            -> False
```

which gets the same error (the former function is just a sugared version of the latter anyway, I think).  If I could get the string, I could construct and compare but that's effectively the same problem with respect to the matching.

Can an instance of a data type be deconstructed without pattern-matching?  I'd rather not add more to the data definition or turn it into a record type.

(BTW, I have got around this by creating an arbitrary token from the constructor, showing the original and constructed terms and then comparing the heads of the words but it feels like a work-around.)

Comment: Why do you have `token` as a polymorphic type variable? Why not just use `Token` directly? For example, would there be a problem with having: `tokenUsesConstructor :: Token -> Bool`?

Comment: You can not use the same variable twice in the head. Haskell uses *pattern matching*, not *unification*. Furthermore you can not use a constructor like that, since `Constructor` allows *any* function, and thus `undefined` would be a candidate as well.

Comment: @David: it's so that the library module can be general and reused with different token definitions by different top-level entry points ... is the aim

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: thanks for observation regarding pattern-matching versus unification.  As for the definition of constructor, it's okay if it's broader than is strictly necessary, the assignments to the constructors are controlled by the program (or a configuration problem, in which case the program has already quit); that is, the constructor passed to tokenUsesConstructor will not be malformed ... if I read you correctly

Answer (score 1):

The constructor part of a pattern must be static; it can’t be a variable. You also can’t use the same variable multiple times in a pattern (“nonlinear” patterns), or use a global variable name as a pattern to try to match that thing by equality; a variable name in a pattern always matches anything, and binds it to a new local variable by that name.

Furthermore, functions are completely opaque and cannot be compared. Even if they could, that wouldn’t be the right thing here: `Constructor token` denotes *any* function of type `String -> token`, not necessarily one of the constructors of your `Token` type.

If you want to do this check dynamically, you can make a separate tag type for tokens and compare against that:

```
data Token = A String | B String
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data Constructor = ConstructorA | ConstructorB
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

tokenConstructor :: Token -> Constructor
tokenConstructor A{} = ConstructorA
tokenConstructor B{} = ConstructorB

tokenUsesConstructor :: Constructor -> Token -> Bool
tokenUsesConstructor c t = tokenConstructor t == c
```

If, as it seems, *all* of your constructors just take a `String` argument, then you can factor out the repetition with a little type algebra (t + t = 2 × t):

```
data Token = Token
  { tokenConstructor :: Constructor
  , tokenString :: String
  }
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

tokenUsesConstructor c t = tokenConstructor t == c
```

Alternatively, you could have this function accept a predicate as an argument, then the test is trivial (and you might not even need a separate function):

```
isA :: Token -> Bool
isA A{} = True
isA _ = False

isB :: Token -> Bool
isB B{} = True
isB _ = False

type Predicate a = a -> Bool

matches :: Predicate token -> token -> Bool
matches p t = p t  -- matches = ($) = id
```

```
> constructor = isA
> matches constructor tokenA
True
```

There are more involved solutions, such as GADTs to make this “tag” known statically, or various ways of making things generic, but I think whether they’re appropriate depends on the details of your actual use case that you haven’t described.

Comment: firstly, thanks for taking the time to respond -- really appreciated -- and apologies for the delayed reply, I've been mulling this over.  It seems neither solution is without its drawbacks :/  The work-around requires `Show token =>` to be added to many signatures, while your solution de-normalises the configuration space (as well as inflating it).  So ... I've opted go with the work-around, because it's already in place, and put an item on the backlog to revisit this when time permits.  Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: @Rik: I’m not quite sure what you mean by “denormalisation” here. If you’re referring to refactoring the type, it depends on whether you consider `a + … + a` “fully normalised” because it’s in “sum of products” form (DNF), or its equivalent `n × a` normalised because it’s fully factored into “product of sums” form (CNF); ultimately “the” form to use is whichever you find a more convenient fit for the problem at hand.